# Rename SharePoint 2019 Content Database Issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, windows-server-2016

I am trying to rename database SharePoint Admin Content database for that I am using below PowerShell commands in **SharePoint 2019**

```
New-SPContentDatabase -Name SharePoint_AdminContent -WebApplication http://sp2010-web1:20376
Get-SPWebApplication -Identity http://sp2010-web1:20376 | Get-SPContentDatabase | Select Id, Name, WebApplication | Format-List
Get-SPSite -ContentDatabase 46410944-32c4-4e01-8390-22b693f4fcc2 | Move-SPSite -DestinationDatabase 86d8e579-fbd8-473e-867d-58b974ee0267
```

But on the last line, I am getting below error

[image]

I also try to upgrade both content databases but it also tells me that upgrade is not needed

[image]

I patch my SharePoint 2019 with **KB4484271** but still, I have the same issue.

[image]

Can somebody help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Any help will be appriciated

Comment: How many servers in your farm? Have you run the SharePoint Configuration wizard on all SP servers after installing the SharePoint updates? if your goal is just to rename the content database why you didn't dismount the content database from a web application and then rename it after that mount it again?

Comment: 1 Front-End with Distributed Cache, 2 Application and 1 Search Server. Yes I have ran PSCONFIG GUI and run well.  I am afraid dismount and mount can damage my SharePoint Farm.

Comment: Take a backup before doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go to Central Admin> Under “Upgrade and Migration”> Click on “Review database status“ to check the database upgrade status.

Or install the latest [security update for SharePoint Server 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4484292/security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2019-april-14) to compare the result.

Then refer to below article to rename the Admin Content Database in SharePoint 2016/2019 using PowerShell:

https://veronicageek.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/rename-admin-content-database-sharepoint-2016-using-powershell/2017/12/

Another way to rename the content databse is to dismount and mount the renamed database again:

https://www.winsysadminblog.com/2016/03/how-to-rename-a-sharepoint-2013-content-database-name-hosted-on-sql-server/

Comment: I have review database, status is no action required, I have tried first link it did not help. I will try second one. and let you know

Comment: This link works https://www.winsysadminblog.com/2016/03/how-to-rename-a-sharepoint-2013-content-database-name-hosted-on-sql-server/ for me

Answer (score 0):

None of the links provided work in SP2019 to rename the CENTRAL ADMIN CONTENT Database.  If there is a way to do it, I haven't discovered it. You'll get this error saying 16.0.156.0 is not equal to 16.0.156.0

[image]